# How to Properly Send to Socket Room?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

The 'message' socket is not working sending to the frontend. I think the problem is originating from my server code, specifically this block:

```
socket.to(data.roomId).emit('message', {
    from: data.from,
    body: data.body,
    timestamp: data.timestamp
  });
```

When I change the above to `socket.emit('message')`, the message is received and rendered on the front end. However, because it's not to the specific roomId, there is no instant chat functionality. I know data.roomId is the proper roomId using a console.log in the proper scope.

Server API

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
//meant to join the socket to the roomId so that messages can be emmitted to the roomId
socket.on('join', function (data) {
      socket.join(data.roomid, () => {
        console.log(data.roomid);
      });
    });

//my Conversation schema holds Message Schemas
socket.on('connected', function (data) {
      //loads all messages already created
      const filter = { roomId: data.roomid };
      (async () => {
        console.log('searching for Schema');
        let conversation = await Conversation.findOne(filter)
          .populate('messages')
          .exec(function (err, message) {
            if (message) {
              const array = message.messages;
              console.log(array);
              socket.emit('send', { arra: array }); //sends previous conversation
            } else {
              console.log('Schema not found');
            }
          });
      })();
    });

    socket.on('server:message', (data) => {
      const filter = { roomId: data.roomId };
      const message = new Message({
        from: data.from,
        body: data.body,
        timestamp: data.timestamp
      });

      (async () => {
        console.log('searching for Schema');

        let conversation = await Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {
          $push: { messages: message }
        });

        if (conversation == null) {
          console.log('Schema being created');
          (await Conversation.create(filter)).populate('messages');
          message.save(function (err) {
            if (err) console.log('an error has occured saving the message');
            // saved!
          });
          await Conversation.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {
            $push: { messages: message }
          });
          let updatedConversation = await Conversation.findOne(filter);
        } else {
          console.log('Schema found');
          let updatedConversation = await Conversation.findOne(filter);
          message.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            // saved!
          });
        }
      })();
      //this socket is not working
      socket.to(data.roomId).emit('message', {
        from: data.from,
        body: data.body,
        timestamp: data.timestamp
      });
    });
});
```

Frontend

```
//this socket is not receiving anything
    ioClient.on('message', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg); //this is not printing anything
      if (isMount) {
        setMessages((previousMessages) => [
          ...previousMessages,
          toChatMessage(msg)
        ]);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you broadcast to a room from a given socket using

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.to('some room').emit('some event');
});
```

Every sockets in the room **excluding** the sender will get the event.

In your case, you need to use `io.to('some room').emit('some event');`
Check out this [Socket.IO Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/rooms/)